# Orange Pi Zero: Wrong Date and Time even given Internet Access

Tags: linux, armbian

I am using Orange Pi Zero and running Armbian Stretch OS 5.59 on it.

Problem is, it is giving wrong date and time even in the presence of the Internet. I have tried restarting "ntp" service but to no avail. I have also tried rebooting, but the same annoying result. I have already set the right timezone which is PKT, but it shouldn't matter. So what do I need to do or change?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Now that I have resolved the problem, I want to share it with others. I had to make changes in "/etc/resolv.conf". Here nameserver field stated "127.0.0.1", I changed it to google nameserver "8.8.8.8". The problem resolved and I have correct date and time now.

But now that I see again, "/etc/resolv.conf" has been overwritten by OS(I believe) and it again displays "127.0.0.1" as my nameserver. But, still I am getting the right date and time. My take is, I needed to coordinate with Google to update correct date and time. But upon reboot, OS retraces any changes made in "/etc/resolv.conf" but changes stick.